# how to call this class from main class or ContactInfromation class

Tags: java, swing

```
public class RetriveUser extends ContactInformation {
    public void retriveUser(){
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container content = this.getContentPane();
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    Connection connection;
    ResultSet resultSet;
    Statement statement = null;
    Vector data = new Vector();

    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/contact_info","root","");
        System.out.println("Connection established");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(retriveUser);
        ResultSetMetaData metaData =resultSet.getMetaData();
        int columns = metaData.getColumnCount();

        while (resultSet.next()){
            Vector row = new Vector(columns);
            for (int i=1; i<=columns; i++){
                row.addElement(resultSet.getObject(i));
            }
            data.addElement(row);

        }


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception occur");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Vector columnName = new Vector();
    columnName.addElement("id");
    columnName.addElement("first_name");
    columnName.addElement("last_name");
    columnName.addElement("district");
    columnName.addElement("city");
    columnName.addElement("address");
    columnName.addElement("father_name");
    columnName.addElement("mobile_no");
    columnName.addElement("email");

    table = new JTable(data,columnName);
    JPanel tabPanel = new JPanel();
    tabPanel.add(table);
    content.add(tabPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

}

I've made a main class and I'm extending main class in this class. So, while I've calling this class from main class like RetriveUser.retriveUser(); it displays non static method cannot be referenced from static method.. so how to calling from main class ContactInformation class.

Comment: You need to instantiate a new Object `new RetriveUser().retriveUser()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main class is static, your `retriveUser()` is not. Either you label your retriveUser method static (which wouldn't work right now since you use instance variables in that method) or your create an instance of your `RetriveUser` like this

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    new RetriveUser().retriveUser();
 }
```

This would solve your problem syntactically, at least.

Please note, that the code for creating a connection to your database should be managed separately. The same is true for the GUI (JTable) and the retrieval of users. You should have at least 3 separate classes for this example.

Comment: thanks its helpful and working ...and thanks for the suggestion for creating separate classes ...

Answer (score 1):

in your main class do something like this:

```
RetriveUser ru = new RetriveUser();
ru.retriveUser();
```